# Unable to access orientdb function through Java API

Tags: java, orientdb

Trying to execute orientdb function through java api.
Find below code

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/test").open("admin", "admin");
OFunction testFunc = db.getMetadata().getFunctionLibrary().getFunction("testfunc");
testFunc.execute();
```

Here I'm getting testFunc as null.
Need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still wondering why the above code is not working as its given in [OrientDB Doc](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Functions.html)
But I've found solution to this.
Here is piece of code that worked.

```
ODatabaseDocumentTx db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("remote:localhost/test").open("admin", "admin");
Integer result = db.command(new OCommandFunction("testfunc")).execute(1,2);
```